# How to properly write file in android to make it available to ADB?

Tags: android, file, adb

Actually i have an app that by receiving a specific intent write a specific txt file with a written in it trace.

To write the file i use the following method

```
public void write(String data, Context context,String filename) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

And till here all is working fine, the file is written but now i need to pull that file via ADB and here come the issue. As the `OutputStreamWriter` is set to `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` adb pull command just can't find that file so which would be the best method to write that file in a "public" directory and then be able to pull that file via ADB?

The ADB commands will be sent from a VB.NET programm.